# Combining subproccess.os with regex to get a filtered list of directories/files

Tags: python, regex, for-loop, subprocess, file-search

I'm new to coding and am having difficulty using subprocess.os with regex. I'm trying to get a list of all the files and directories that start with an uppercase C. This is what I've got so far...

```
home = subprocess.os.path.expanduser("~")

FilesDirsStartingWithC = []

for (dir, subdir, files) in subprocess.os.walk(home):
    match = re.findall(r'^C\w+')
    for i in match:
        FilesDirsStartingWithC.append(i)
print(FilesDirsStartingWithC)
```

I realise the part between the first for statement and the append statement is wrong but I can't figure out how to fix it. Any help would be much appreciated! Thank you :)

Comment: it seems you're missing an argument in `re.findall`

Comment: If your question is answered, kindly accept it.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use re module. Its just os.walk() and .startswith():

```
import os

catalogs = []
for root, dirs, files in os.walk('D:/'):
    for Dir in dirs:
        if Dir.startswith('C'):
            catalogs.append(Dir)

print(catalogs)
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Extend your with matched lists:

```
home = subprocess.os.path.expanduser("~")

FilesDirsStartingWithC = []

for (dirs, subdirs, files) in subprocess.os.walk(home):
    FilesDirsStartingWithC.extend(re.findall('^C\w+', ''.join(dirs)))
    FilesDirsStartingWithC.extend(re.findall('^C\w+', ''.join(subdirs)))
    FilesDirsStartingWithC.extend(re.findall('^C\w+', ''.join(files)))
print(FilesDirsStartingWithC)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to walk and capture both **directories** and **files**, you can do as suggested earlier by @min-protector but merge the directories, d, and files, f, first:

```
import os

paths = []
for r, d, f in os.walk('/home/'):

    d_and_f = d + f

    for item in d_and_f:
        if item.startswith('C'):
            paths.append(os.path.join(os.sep, r, item))
```

Note that I am using os.path.join to add the root, r, to the directories and files paths, to ensure identifying duplications. Without this, the output for `\path1\C1` and `\path2\C1` will be `['C1', 'C1']`

Or you can use list List Comprehensions:

```
paths = [os.path.join(os.sep, r,item) 
            for r,d,f in os.walk('/home/') 
            for item in d + f 
            if item.startswith('C')]
```